# Strange behaviour for functions

Tags: c++, overloading

so basically i have an overloaded function to calculate the norm:

```
double Szabo::norme(Gaussienne gaussienne, Atome atome) {
    return sqrt(pow(gaussienne.GetX()-atome.x,2)+pow(gaussienne.GetY()-atome.y,2)+pow(gaussienne.GetY()-atome.y,2));
}

double Szabo::norme(Gaussienne gaussienneA, Gaussienne gaussienneB)
{
    return sqrt(pow(gaussienneA.GetX()-gaussienneB.GetX(),2.0) + pow(gaussienneA.GetY()-gaussienneB.GetY(),2.0) + pow(gaussienneA.GetZ()-gaussienneB.GetZ(),2.0));
}
```

Gaussienne & Atome (class & structure) are defined like this:

Atome:

```
struct Atome
{
    double x; double y; double z; double numeroAtomique;
};
```

Gaussienne:

```
#ifndef GaussienneHeader
class Gaussienne
{       
    protected:
        // attributs
        double alpha;
        double coordX,coordY,coordZ;
    public:
        // methodes:

            // Constructeurs:
            Gaussienne();
            Gaussienne(double alpha,double x, double y, double z);

            // Accesseurs:
            double GetAlpha() const; //return this->alpha
            double GetX() const; //return this coordX
            double GetY() const; // return this coordY
            double GetZ() const; // return this coordZ

};

#define GaussienneHeader
#endif
```

So now, i wanna calculate the norm between the center of 2 gaussians A & B, and the atom located in (0,0,0);

I create a "placeholder" gaussian like this to store the coordinate of the center of the prevous to

```
Gaussienne gaussienneP(0,(gaussienneA.GetX()+gaussienneB.GetX())/2.0,(gaussienneA.GetY()+gaussienneB.GetY())/2.0,(gaussienneA.GetZ()+gaussienneB.GetZ())/2.0);
```

when i call this:

```
Szabo::norme(mygaussian,atome)
```

i got different result than when calling this:

```
/* using this constructor: Gaussienne(double alpha,double x, double y, double z) with a dummy alpha = 0; */
Szabo::norme(mygaussian,Gaussienne(0,atome.x,atome.y,atome.z)
```

Fortunatly i can compare my results to some "canon" program, so i know that the norme function with the two gaussians return the good results, however the other isn't.

Can anyone provide me and explanation regarding the strange behavior of this? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think the error is here :

```
double Szabo::norme(Gaussienne gaussienne, Atome atome) {
    return sqrt(pow(gaussienne.GetX()-atome.x,2)+pow(gaussienne.GetY()-atome.y,2)+pow(gaussienne.GetY()-atome.y,2));
}
```

the y component is used twice, it should be :

```
double Szabo::norme(Gaussienne gaussienne, Atome atome) {
    return sqrt(pow(gaussienne.GetX()-atome.x,2)+pow(gaussienne.GetY()-atome.y,2)+pow(gaussienne.GetZ()-atome.z,2));
}
```

Comment: lmao i'm so stupid, thanks bro. I shouldn't work on this at midnight ;)

Comment: @devo this is why you write a `location` type, define `operator-` on it, and `length_squared` and `length` and scalar division/multiplication.  Then test and stop writing coord-specific stuff in the middle of other logic.  Because errors are easy.